# <Location Path=""> not working in web.config (in full IIS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, iis-7.5

I am trying to add allow all to my content anonymous access in my content directory for my css and js files bit it is not working.

**This works in IIS Express but not the full IIS.**

A section from my web.config is below.

```
<!-- Show default CSS and image-->
  <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

   <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <compilation debug="true" 
                 targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/SignIn" 
             path="/" />
    </authentication>
.....
```

Comment: I have enabled Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication, am I missing anything ie Basic Auth?

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

`*` means only authenticated users. Use a `?` to denote anonymous users. Source: [ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx).

Comment: It works in IIS Express with the `*` but seems to ingore the location rule completly in the full IIS

Answer (score 1):

Besides enabling Anonymous Authentication for the web site, I had to go a step further and Edit Anonymous Authentication (by right clicking) and change it from a Specific User to Application pool identity.

Answer (score 0):

try doing the following:

1. First ensure you use question mark symbol `?` which denotes anonymous user access. Also, to be able to interpret the `?` option you should enable the value `IIS site > Authentication > Anonymous Authentication > Enabled`
2. Next you might need to enter the `Edit...` screen and set the user to an explicit one (and AD user is prefered in web farm scenario) or the current application pool identity.

The location XML should be:

```
<location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Notice the `?` value which differs from `*` which you added in the question.